# Android View Pager with rounded corner

Tags: android, xml, android-viewpager

I am working on ViewPager and its working fine. Now i want to modify design of pager in a way that pages are display with rounded corners.
I have created a xml for it.
Below is my xml -

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >

  <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
  <corners android:radius="50px"/>
  <padding 
      android:left="0dp" 
      android:top="0dp" 
      android:right="0dp"         
      android:bottom="0dp" />
```

and here is my viewpager item view -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

      <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:padding="20dp" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/round_bg" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/event_iv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

  </RelativeLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

when running code it  display square. Rounded corner are not applied to my view.

Please help me

Thanks  in advance.

**EDITED**

below is parent xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/generic_vp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_event_bg" />
```

Comment: is the background color same as your parent background color?

Comment: no parent bg is an texture image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `ImageLoader` for download Image it will help to make rounded `ImageView`

```
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(thisContext)
        // You can pass your own memory cache implementation
       .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator())
       .build();

DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(10)) //rounded corner bitmap
        .cacheInMemory(true)
        .cacheOnDisc(true)
        .build();

ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
imageLoader.init(config);
imageLoader.displayImage(image_url,image_view, options );
```

Comment: My view pager bg is an texture image

Comment: you posted code is perfect.!! post more code (main)

Comment: as i debug app found that initially when page load its with rounded corner but after image is being downloaded in pager pager is display square.

Comment: set margin on `event_iv` `ImageView`

Comment: you have to make rounded imageview rather than view pager background

Comment: i have one more issue in view pager. My view pager next page is visible but not show previous page. Can you please help me in this too.